# I entered ‘pip’ in my cmd,but there's an error:Fatal error in launcher: Failed to open executable.What can I do now?

Tags: pip, python-3.5

I entered ‘pip’ in my cmd（Windows10）,but there's an error:Fatal error in launcher: Failed to open executable.What can I do now?

[image]

Comment: PATH environment may be.., BTW asking to click on link or posting links in question is a bad idea and over time links really disappear leaving your question dangling with partial inputs

Answer (score 0):

Try this one it worked for me:

> python -m pip